# Tabular inside listings

Tags: tables, listings, code

I'm trying to get this

[image]

with this style [image]

but I'm getting the error `! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit \@multispan`

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,etoolbox,lmodern}
\definecolor{verbgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand*\prompt{}
\lstnewenvironment{sh}{
  \def\prompt{usuario@linux:\textasciitilde\$\space}
  \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{verbgray},
    frame=single,
    framerule=.5pt,
    columns=fullflexible,
    escapechar=@
  }
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{sh}
@\prompt\textbf{cal}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Enero 2015}   \\
do & lu & ma & mi & ju & vi & sa \\
   &    &    &    &  1 &  2 &  3 \\
 4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 & 10 \\
11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 \\
\end{tabular}@
\end{sh}
\end{document}
```

Comment: listings is essentially a "verbatim" environent with some syntax highlighting, why are you putting tex markup for anything, especially a table in listings?

Comment: I don't remember why I began doing these boxes with the listings environment but I can still change it. What environment would you recommend?

Comment: You could either use listings as Jubobs suggests, using it as intended showing the verbatim output text, or if you want a tes-typeset table with a fancy box around it mdframed or tcolorbox for example will do all kinds of background colours and borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David wrote in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225050/tabular-inside-listings#comment528945_225050), `listings` is mainly for verbatim contents. If you have this much markup in an "escape to LaTeX" within a listing, you're doing something wrong.

You're essentially hardcoding the output of the shell command `cal 8 1973` into your `lstlisting` environment. Embedding it into a `tabular` within an escape to LaTeX seems convoluted and unnecessary. Why not simply

- copy and paste the output into the `lstlisting` environment, and
- set

  ```
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  columns    = fixed,
  ```

to get proper alignment? You can always use a different typewriter font, if you don't like the default one.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor,etoolbox,lmodern}

\definecolor{verbgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand*\prompt{}
\lstnewenvironment{sh}{
  \def\prompt{usuario@linux:\textasciitilde\$\space}
  \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{verbgray},
    frame=single,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    framerule=.5pt,
    columns=fixed,
    escapechar=@
  }
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{sh}
@\prompt@cal 8 1973
    August 1973
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31
\end{sh}
\end{document}
```