# Side-by-side layout only on some lines of listing

Tags: listings

How is the following achieved?

[image: code]

I've done the blue parts with `escapeinside`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left}

\begin{document} 

% this achieves the first two lines
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*}{*)}]
  (*\{\texttt{emp}\}*)
  barrier b = new barrier(2);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

but adding a table in the same way seems like a [bad idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225050/tabular-inside-listings). I'm not sure how else to do the || parts within a listing.

Alternatively this could be a bunch of nested tables with formatting applied manually... is there a better way, making use of listings, so I don't have to reinvent e.g. line numbers?

Comment: Edited to include that.