# Non-centered table alignment

Tags: tables

I'm trying to build a layout like this:

[image: code]

The first thing which comes to mind is nested `tabular`s, and this sort of works.

[image: more code]

However, how do I align lines 1-4 with the (leftmost) `||` row delimiter spanning lines 5-19?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tabular}{ c }
${\{ \mathit{emp} \}}$ \\
\texttt{barrier b = new barrier(2);} \\
  \begin{tabular}{c||c}
    ${\{ \mathit{left} \}}$ & ${\{ \mathit{right} \}}$ \\
    \texttt{wait(b)} & \texttt{wait(b)} \\
    \texttt{wait(b)} & \begin{tabular}{c||c}
       ${\{ \mathit{left}' \}}$ & ${\{ \mathit{right}'' \}}$ \\
       \texttt{remove(b,1)} & \texttt{remove(b,1)} \\
     \end{tabular} \\
   \end{tabular} \\
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577239/side-by-side-layout-only-on-some-lines-of-listing

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your table isn't complex enough at the moment. In the sketch I try to highlight what you'd need:

- 3 columns (green), which you probably had in mind
- 4 blocks (dark violet), which merge 2 columns (col1+2, col2+3, col2+3, col1+2)

Because you want a matrix-like representation in the middle, perhaps you will be more successful with package `nicematrix`, which is similar to tabular.

[image: sketch of required columns and rows/blocks]

Here's some code, showing the basic structuring, which can get or keep you going. I suggest to 1) expand at this coarse level until you have your layout, 2) start replacing content of ABC etc. with yours, 3) perhaps use macro-definitions at the beginning to enhance readability of your matrix/table structure AND from your formulas (macro replaces ABC with your formula(s) from the top left etc.). I.e. start simple, make it correct, expand on it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
% you may need to compile at least twice for proper display
\begin{document} 
    $\begin{bNiceArray}{c|c|c}  % centering all columns; | for inidcation
        \Block{1-2}{ABC} & & \\ % see R#1
        & \Block{1-2}{DEF}  \\  % see R#2
        GGG & HHH & III \\      % just to display something
    \end{bNiceArray}$

% R#1: \Block spans 1 row, 2 columns; & & indicate the tab stops
% R#2: same, but starting to merge at col 2
\end{document}
```

Result after 2 compiles:

[image: basic column spanning structure]

P.S.: As you can see, the column widths are adjusted automatically, i.e. they depend on the amount of "text" written there. See the III part as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I did think of breaking it down this way, with a multicolumn setup, but I was hoping not to have to deal with manually sizing the green columns. Since the code is hierarchical, it'd be nice to only have to specify the purple blocks and have the layout automated when composing them together.